# Oracle OCI-Lob and ActiveRecord in Yii2

Tags: yii2

I have a CLOB column in my oracle db, but when I fetch it via ActiveRecord findOne,
I get this error:

Object of class OCI-Lob could not be converted to string

I know there is a workaround using dao, but my question is:
Is there a way to work with ActiveRecord and CLOB?

Thank you